# SQL SERVER - Trigger to restrict over 3 records

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-insert, restrict

I am a beginner on SQL and need help setting a Trigger

I need to set a trigger so that if 1 tutor has over 3 different schedule ID's this is not allowed!!

Table

```
TutorID/ScheduleID/Student
1       1           Tom 
1       1           Harry   
1       1           Lima    
1       2           Zany    
1       2           Logan   
1       3           Zoe
1       3           Lana
```

Tutor ID/ Tutor Name
1         Sam

how can I restrict someone from inserting another class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER:** To be completely honest I'm not convinced doing this through a SQL Trigger is the best solution, far better to control this sort of thing through your business layer.

That said you could use a trigger to prevent the insertion:

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger ON dbo.ClassTable
AFTER INSERT
AS

IF EXISTS (SELECT TutorId, COUNT(ScheduleId) 
           FROM db.ClassTable
           GROUP BY TutorID
           HAVING COUNT(ScheduleId) > 3)
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK
    RAISERROR ('Too many classes scheduled!', 16, 1);
END
GO
```

Or if you prefer you can do an INSTEAD OF trigger and just silently discard the pesky extra row :)

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER MyTrigger ON dbo.ClassTable
INSTEAD OF INSERT
 AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT dbo.ClassTable(TutorId, ScheduleId, Student)
        SELECT TutorId, ScheduleId, Student
        FROM inserted
        WHERE TutorId IN (SELECT TutorId, COUNT(ScheduleId) FROM db.ClassTable WHERE COUNT(ScheduleId) < 3 GROUP BY TutorID);
    END
GO
```

Comment: I think your "Instead of Insert" trigger assumes that only 1 record is being inserted. What if there are 2 records being inserted for a tutor, while 2 already exist? Also I think your count check in the where clause needs to be changed to `<=3`

Comment: `<=3` would allow a fourth record to be included, although good point that a multiple record insertion would be problematic

Comment: the numbers in RAISERROR (note it's only got one 'E') are severity and state values see [here](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-stored-procedures/sql-server-raiserror/)

Comment: @gstar I've fixed a syntax error with the trigger - apologies I was half asleep when I wrote it, and yes the way to test it would be to try and do an INSERT for  a 4th class, it should at that point fail to insert the row and give you the error instead

Comment: @gstar be aware that this will only stop a 4th class being INSERTed  - if someone does an `UPDATE` on an existing row you can still exceed the limit, unless that is you do a similar trigger on UPDATE for the same condition.